# NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()

Tags: java, hibernate, maven-2

Hello all 
I'm getting this very strange error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()Lor
g/hibernate/classic/Session;
        at org.cometd.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUt
il.java:29)
        at org.cometd.hibernate.util.HibernateUtil.getSession(HibernateUtil.java
:54)
```

But this method exists in SessionFactory class in JavaDocs! 
My Eclipse also shows me it in the autocomplete. 
But some other methods, i.e. openSession() or closeSession() work correct. 
Where the problem can hide? 
My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">



    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <overlays>
                        <overlay />
                        <overlay>
                            <groupId>org.cometd.javascript</groupId>
                            <artifactId>cometd-javascript-dojo</artifactId>
                        </overlay>
                    </overlays>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>6.1.24</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/sample</contextPath>
                    </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.javascript</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-javascript-dojo</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-java-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
            <!--<version>3.6.0.Final</version>-->
        </dependency>               
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10</version>
            <!-- <scope>runtime</scope>  -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10</version>
            <!-- <scope>runtime</scope>  -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <!-- <scope>runtime</scope>  -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmock</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmock-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId> 
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version> 
        </dependency> 

        <!-- Hibernate framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate3</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate annotation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hibernate-annotations</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>hibernate-commons-annotations</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.0.GA</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

P.S. the code is

```
org.hibernate.SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

org.hibernate.Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

Comment: Sounds like you might have a copy of Hibernate 2 kicking about in your classpath

Comment: Hi skaffman, no, I have never downloaded Hibernate 2, only the third version.

Comment: I run the app using mvn jetty plugin (jetty:run)

Comment: That might be your intention, yes, but maven has a habit of pulling down stuff you don't expect.

Comment: @skaffman: Well if it occured, how may I fix it? Add hibernate3.jar manually to classpath?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it might be down to multiple hibernate version on the classpath. Looks like too many here...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        <!--<version>3.6.0.Final</version>-->
    </dependency>               
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

....

<dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate3</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3.GA</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Hibernate annotation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate-annotations</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>hibernate-commons-annotations</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Absolutely right answer. I did have `hibernate3.jar` and `hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar` both in the class path as lib. Just I removed `hibernate3.jar` and it works fine. Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

For **Hibernate 4.1.1** I have added

```
 <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```

to hibernate.config.xml

For **Hibernate 3** I have added

```
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```

It resolved my problemn