# JSP with maven and hibernate - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError, probably issue with project structure

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, maven, nosuchmethoderror

I have a problem with my school project. Im using hibernate,jsp and maven for dependency management. Hibernate and maven works fine but when I try to make a simple jsp page with login screen. Its not working. I think problem is with maven and how he works with project structure, because if I make test class everything working. Im not able to find anything about how maven works with webapps.

Sorry for my mistakes in english :).

my project structure:

```
├── src
│   └── main
│       ├── java
│       │    │
│       │    pro3
│       │     ├── model
│       │     │   ├── dao
│       │     │   │   ├── DaoInterface.java
│       │     │   │   └── HibernateDao.java
│       │     │   ├── hibernate
│       │     │   │   ├── hibernate.cfg.xml
│       │     │   │   ├── hibernate.reveng.xml
│       │     │   │   ├── HibernateUtil.java
│       │     │   │   ├── mapping
│       │     │   │   │   ├── Meal.hbm.xml
│       │     │   │   │   ├── ...
│       │     │   │   │   
│       │     │   │   └── Test.java
│       │     │   └── pojo
│       │     │       ├── Meal.java
│       │     │       ├── ...
│       │     │      
│       │     │      
│       │     └── utils
│       │         └── LoginHandler.java
│       └── webapp
│           └── index.jsp
```

Index.jsp:

```
<jsp:useBean id="login" scope="page" class="cz.fim.pro3.utils.LoginHandler" />
...
login.verifyUser(request.getParameter("userName"), request.getParameter("password"));
```

LoginHandler.java:

```
public class LoginHandler {
    DaoInterface dao = new HibernateDao();


    public boolean verifyUser(String userName,String password){
        return dao.verifyUser(userName, password);
    }
}
```

HibernateDao.java:

```
public boolean verifyUser(String userName, String password)
```

In my test class everything works fine, when I run it as java application.

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
    LoginHandler login = new LoginHandler();
    login.verifyUser("sdf", "asda");
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <!-- this is relative to the pom.xml directory -->
                        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <!-- enable filtering -->
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target> 1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<packaging>war</packaging>
```

error trace:

```
Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/Session;
    at cz.fim.pro3.model.dao.HibernateDao.verifyUser(HibernateDao.java:11)
    at cz.fim.pro3.utils.LoginHandler.verifyUser(LoginHandler.java:11)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:83)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: Refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4324068/1285418), if not solve your problem, post full pom.xml source..

Comment: thank you very much. It not solved my problem directly, but give me the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing i can recommend is to change the locations of your files, cause in Maven you have to [follow some conventions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html):

The Java files should be put into *src/main/java* plus the appropriate package name.
The hibernate.cfg.xml file and the hibernate.reveng.xml do **NOT** belong to src/main/java they have to be located into *src/main/resources* plus the appropriate package name you like to put them into. Furthermore in hibernate the mapping should be handled by annotations and not by hbm files anymore. But if you have to stuck with the mappings files they have to be put into *src/main/resources* as well.

If you have some kind of tests (usually unit tests) like Test.java they have to be put into *src/test/java* any kind of resources which belong to the unit tests only have to be put into *src/test/resources* plus the appropriate package name. 
The jsp file have been located correctly into *src/main/webapp*.

Apart from the above you have to call the correct method in your **HibernateDao.java** line **11** where you are trying to call a method **openSession** which obviously does not exists.