# hibernate dependency issue for spring 4 after upgrading to hibernate 5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

Below is my pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.dvdme</groupId>
        <artifactId>ForecastIOLib</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.wewherego</groupId>
        <artifactId>api-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.lambdaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>lambdaj</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.98</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The hibernate config is set up by annotations:

public class HibnerateConfiguration {

```
//declarations that are ignored

public static AnnotationConfiguration config() throws IOException {
    AnnotationConfiguration hibernateConfig = new AnnotationConfiguration();
    hibernateConfig.setProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT_STRING, HIBERNATE_DIALECT_MYSQL_VALUE);
    hibernateConfig.setProperty(HIBERNATE_DRIVER_CLASS_STRING, HIBERNATE_DRIVER_CLASS_MYSQL_VALUE);
    String jdbcString = "jdbc:"
            + getHost()
            + ":"
            + .getPort()
            + "/"
            + getDBName()
            + "?autoReconnect=true";
    hibernateConfig.setProperty(HIBERNATE_DB_URL_STRING, jdbcString);
    hibernateConfig.setProperty(HIBERNATE_DB_USERNAME_STRING, getUser());
    hibernateConfig.setProperty(HIBERNATE_DRIVER_PW_STRING, getPassword());
    hibernateConfig.setProperty(HIBERNATE_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS_STRING, HIBERNATE_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS_VALUE);
    hibernateConfig.setProperty(HIBERNATE_TIMEOUT_STRING, HIBERNATE_TIMEOUT_VALUE);
    hibernateConfig.addAnnotatedClass(myClass.class);
    return hibernateConfig;
}
```

}

When handling sessions, I have:

package com.wewherego.api.malloc.infrastructure;

```
public class SessionHandler {
    private static SessionFactory sessions= null;
    static {
        try {
            if (sessions== null) {
                synchronized (SessionFactory.class) {
                    sessions= HibnerateConfiguration.config().buildSessionFactory();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(t);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Returns a session anyway. If currently no session exist, open a new one;
     * If there is a current session, use the existing one.
     * ***NOTE: potential issue in this method when dealing with session like this***
     */
    @Override
    public Session getSession() {
        try {
            return sessions.getCurrentSession();
        }
        catch (HibernateException he) {
            return sessions.getCurrentSession();
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        sessions.close();
    }
}
```

And it is being used as:

```
session.createQuery(String.format("FROM %s", "myTable"));
```

In the

will throw this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.Session.createQuery(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/hibernate/query/Query;
```

In runtime, the dependencies are:

[image: runtime dependencies]

The hibernate documentation still have createQuery in the Session class: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#createQuery(java.lang.String)

but sure what did I miss?

Comment: For starters stop mixing hibernate versions... You are mixing 3.2.6, 5.1.0 and 5.2.3 if yu want trouble that I the way to go.

Comment: I've faced same problem while writing some sample project with Hibernate java configuration approach. And i have to admit that, this problem DOES NOT persists in hibernate versions under 5.2.x ( better 2.0) so i'd suggest you to downgrade some dependencies in order to get it working. Also @PRATHAP S is correct at some point

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the suggestion - hibernate's 3.2.6 comes from the hibernate-annotation, whose latest version is only 3.x - is it any substitution to this?

Comment: @Reborn instead of downgrading some dependencies, is it a way to update the code so that it would work?

Comment: @jamesdeath123 sorry, i didn't figured it out what was the problem back then so decided to rush it. Could you attach config file for hibernate?

Comment: @jamesdeath123 i just found interesting thing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324068/nosuchmethoderror-org-hibernate-sessionfactory-getcurrentsession... maybe some dependencies for m hibernate conflicting with spring ? If that so, then you have to analyze for simlarities and disable via spring annotations.

Comment: you don't need hibernate annotations as that is integrated now, just remove that dependency.

Comment: @Reborn I have updated the configuration done in my code.

Comment: hey @M.Deinum now I have added the part I did the configuration with annotations - please advise :)

Comment: Your configuration isn't the problem your conflicting dependencies are the issue you aren't going to solve that with configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum yeah you are right - I put the config part because I was using AnnotationConfiguration which is deprecated in newer verson. I used the Configuration and it wasn't a problem any more, so I was able to remove the hibernate-annotations dependency and the hibernate 3.2.6 is gone now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two versions of hibernate on your classpath : 3.2.6 and 5.2. Remove the version 3.2.6

The issue is in part due to hibernate project which changed their maven artifact name between version 3.2 and 3.3, making maven version conflict handling ineffective.

To see what is pulling version 3.2.6 in your project use the command :

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

You'll get the dependency tree. Find what is pulling hibernate.jar, and then use excludes the dependency with `<excludes>` tags.

From looking quickly at your dependency list, this dependency is not needed, because annotations are included directly in hibernate-core.jar (or one of the dependency pulled by hibernate-core) :

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
     <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
</dependency>
```

and it is [pulling hibernate 3.2.6.ga](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.3.1.GA). Remove it, and retry, it might be the only one pulling hibernate 3.2.6.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have updated the question to include my hibernate configuration. After removing the hibernate-annotations but then it gives me compile error in my HibernateConfuguration class: AnnotationConfiguration cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: oh mvn, found that AnnotationConfiguration is deprecated and now I am using hibernate.cfg.Configuration. It works now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Any of the Following might be missing at your configuration

1. `Session session = HibnerateConfiguration.config().buildSessionFactory();` This will return `SessionFactory` not `Session`
2. Hibernate 5 you need two jars: hibernate-core and hibernate-entitymanager, I think hibernate-entitymanager is missing
3. hibernate.cfg.xml or any form of applicationContext should be in the root of the classpath of your application

Need to see the configuration file and the classpath of the application

Comment: 1 - thanks for the catch. I have updated the question; was a copy/paste error. 2 - hibernate-entitymanager is deprecated in hibernate 5, you only need hibernate-core: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager 3 - I am using AnnotationConfiguration and it works for other ways of querying, such as criteria.list(), just not this one so I don't think it relates to the hibernate's configuration.

Comment: `// A SessionFactory is set up once for an application!
 final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
   .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
   .build();
 try {
  sessionFactory = new MetadataSources( registry ).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
 }`

can try creating session factory in this way

Comment: Have you deleted all your old dependencies from `c:\Users\username\.m2\repository` or have you run `maven force update` ?

Comment: thanks for the follow up - I have updated my question to include more info regards to the SessionFactory and hibernate config. I have tried deleting all dependencies from .m2 but that didn't help.

Comment: deleting them from the repo will not help as long as they are in the pom they will reappear.

Comment: They ll reappear as a new version, since they have upgraded the version, sometimes old dependencies will not be replaced (in rare cases ) @M. Deinum

Comment: those rare case are rare cases and have nothing to do with cleaning the repo. Generally that is only an issue in your IDE and not when  building from the command line. Generally cleaning your .m2 directory only cleans up space temporarily.